# Проблема с выводом Объекта из файла

Tags: java

Создаю небольшое приложение, при нажатии на кнопку регистрации создается объект.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(tfLogin.getText().length()>=0 && tfPassword.getText().length()>=0 && tfPasswordTwo.getText().equals(tfPassword.getText())){
                AllGamers.saveAccaunt(new LoginAndPass(tfLogin.getText(), tfPassword.getText()));
            }
```

Потом объект сохраняется в файл:

```
    public static void saveAccaunt(LoginAndPass gamers){

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("SaveAc",true);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(gamers);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Тут работает всё нормально, когда считываю файл тоже всё нормально:

```
        try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("SaveAc");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        Object o = objectInputStream.readObject();
        LoginAndPass l1 = (LoginAndPass) o;

        System.out.println(l1.getLogin());
        System.out.println(l1.getPassword());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда хочу в файл добавить ещё один аккаунт, то есть ещё один объект, вроде оно его добавляет, но когда пытаюсь их считать то выдаёт ошибку:

```
 try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("SaveAc");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        Object o = objectInputStream.readObject();
        LoginAndPass l1 = (LoginAndPass) o;

        System.out.println(l1.getLogin());
        System.out.println(l1.getPassword());

        Object o1 = objectInputStream.readObject();
        LoginAndPass l2 = (LoginAndPass) o1;

        System.out.println(l2.getLogin());
        System.out.println(l2.getPassword());


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Вот код ошибки:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at Registratsiya.AllGamers.main(AllGamers.java:32)
```

Comment: Есть мнение, что записывать объекты в файл нужно в одном потоке. Тогда они будут прочитаны. А если сначала записать один, потом дописать другой, но другим потоком (new ObjectOutputStream), то тогда и получается то, что получили. AC - это типа заголовок нового потока ObjectOutputStream, вместо кода class-а

Comment: А что тогда стоит делать?

Comment: Может так, как здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607969/appending-objects-to-a-serialization-file

Comment: Всё вроде как работает но выбивает java.io.EOFException

Comment: Первым делом убедитесь, что не пытаетесь читать из файла лишнее. Например цикл чтения делает лишнию итерацию.